# Everything inside a cog file seems to be correct, but doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

The problem is that all the code inside the main file and the cog file is correct although for some reason `on_message()`
 doesn't work. I do not get any exception while running this, but it does not do anything in discord.

**This is the main code, this also loads the cogs.**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env')
token = os.getenv('TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(' Made by Termed#6382')
    print(' Bot events are logged below : ')
    print(' ----------')
    for file in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if file.endswith('.py') and not file.startswith('_'):
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{file[:-3]}')
            print(' Loaded {}'.format(file))

client.run(token)
bot.run(token)
```

**This is the cog file, inside a cog folder**

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

class onMessage(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(message):
        message_content = message.content
        if message_content.isupper():
            if message.author.id == 'XX':
                await message.channel.send('{}No u'.format(message.author.mention))
            message_author = message.author
            await message.channel.send('{} , Please refrain from using too many capital letters.'.format(message.author.mention))
            print(' Warned {} for too many capital letters'.format(message_author))

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(onMessage(bot))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use both `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')` and `client = discord.Client()`. These will both create separate instances of Discord bots, with `bot` using the `commands` extension.

Remove `client` and use `bot` throughout your code. You also don't need to specify `client = discord.Client()` in your cog.

**main**

```
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env')
token = os.getenv('TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(' Made by Termed#6382')
    print(' Bot events are logged below : ')
    print(' ----------')
    for file in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if file.endswith('.py') and not file.startswith('_'):
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{file[:-3]}')
            print(' Loaded {}'.format(file))

bot.run(token)
```

**cog**

```
from discord.ext import commands

class onMessage(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(message):
        message_content = message.content
        if message_content.isupper():
            if message.author.id == 'XX':
                await message.channel.send('{}No u'.format(message.author.mention))
            message_author = message.author
            await message.channel.send('{} , Please refrain from using too many capital letters.'.format(message.author.mention))
            print(' Warned {} for too many capital letters'.format(message_author))

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(onMessage(bot))
```